# What is blocking in async or sync?

Tags: asynchronous, operating-system, synchronization, blocking

I'm thinking about async / sync / blocking / non-blocking while learning OS. I read many articles but, these just focused on non-blocking or how async does work with a simple picture. But I want to know what blocking really is in the more **big picture including CPU, Memory, OS, I/O Device** etc.

So, this picture is my guess.

[image]

I think the **blocking** means that My App's code is not processed by CPU from **1 until 5**. Am I right?
And my understanding of blocking is right?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not simple, You may have to look at the javascript [event loop](https://medium.com/@kvosswinkel/is-javascript-synchronous-or-asynchronous-what-the-hell-is-a-promise-7aa9dd8f3bfb). Because you are using async, await it does not mean your application is blocked, they are used to avoid writing complex [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) or promise chains. When your are using async and await the javascript will add those executions as required to the event loop to  avoid executions that may need one execution completed before the next one.

But in the meantime it will execute other executions, which is not related to each other and wait one for finish (maybe rendering the webpage while HTTP response comes in).

So in big picture your app will only use one CPU thread. All other non blocking magic happens due to the the implementation of event loop, which makes your application non blocking, but not asynchronous (No matter what a javascript process is always a synchronous process).

If you need real asynchronous executions on your nodejs or javascript. Child Processes and web workers may help you to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to learn this is to look at an operating system that has synchronous and asnchronous I/O system services. Windoze under the covers and (best example) VMS are such operating systems.

In the VMS operating system, the SYS$QIO and SYS$QIOW perform I/O operations.The two system services have identical parameters. One of those parameters (optional) is the address of a routine to be called when the I/O operation completes (known as an AST) and another (option) is a parameter to pass to that routine.

If your application calls SYS$QIO, that function returns immediately after the I/O operations is queued and the application can continue to do other processing. The application has to rely on the callback routine to know when the I/O is done.

If your application calls SYS$QIOW, that function waits (suspends the process) until the I/O operation is complete.

When such non-blocking I/O is available as under SYS$QIO, your application can set up loops of asynchronous operations. Let's say your application wants to handle an arbitrary number of network connections where data can come in at any time. For each connection, you call SYS$QIO to read from the connection. Your process does not wait so it can do that for any number of connections. When data comes in, the AST function gets called and you so another call to SYS$QIO (giving the same function as the AST) to do the next read.

Using this method a single program can handle hundreds (as any as the system parameters will allow) of network connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will stop at a **synchronous** request (whatever it is doing) and wait until the request finished.

PRO: on the next line in your app you can rely that this sync request has done whatever it was doing

CONTRA: your app just sits and waits. It is **blocked**.

Your app will **not** stop at an **asynchronous** request (whatever it is doing).

PRO: App will continue working. It is **not blocked**

CONTRA: if you need to know when the request is finished and what it’s result is, you need take special care to get the result (using callbacks or events or promises or whatever technology is used in your technological framework)